# How do I get the selected text in desktop application using python-dbus?

Tags: python, text, gtk, selection, dbus

For example, I open a pdf file or a web page in gnome, use mouse double click some text, so a word is selected, how can I get this word in a background running daemon written with python-dbus?

Some simple but working piece of script is appreciated greatly.

Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK, this behavior is application dependent: if Application X doesn't export the text, you are out of luck.  Use D-feet or alike to introspect the methods of an application.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need D-Bus, simply listen to changes for the middle-click (Selection) clipboard with for example Gtk:

```
import gtk

def _clipboard_changed(clipboard, event):
    text = clipboard.wait_for_text()

clip = gtk.clipboard_get(gtk.gdk.SELECTION_PRIMARY)
clip.connect("owner-change", _clipboard_changed)
```

Comment: WOW, awesome! Works great!  Just need an extra line:
     gtk.main()
to let the program keep running.

I want to implement something like the usual translation software. I guess I can open up a new window and place it around the mouse.

And only if I can insert dynamic annotate to the pdf files being read, perfect.

Comment: I had trouble with the gtk.gdk.SELECTION_PRIMARY. It only contained clips that had been manually copied using the mouse. I sometimes populate the clipboard using `xclip` in a bash terminal, so the selection setting that works for me (for both mouse and scripted clipboard content updates) was `gtk.gdk.SELECTION_CLIPBOARD`. I also added a conditional to check for `NoneType` before passing the contents on, otherwise you will get the string "None" in your variable named `text` above.

Answer (score 0):

[Gnome Do](https://code.launchpad.net/do) has a few plug-ins that use the selected text. I'm not sure how it is implemented (and if it uses DBus), but the code should reveal all. :)